# A simple linear algebra manipulation problem (please help me come up with a better title)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us say that the vectors $\mathbf{f}_1,..., \mathbf{f}_n$ (collectively referred to as $\mathbf{f}_i$) form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$. In addition, they are the complete set of eigenvectors of the matrix $\mathcal{A}$. The matrix $\mathcal{F}$ has as its columns the vectors $\mathbf{f}_i$.

We have that: $$\mathcal{A}\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{v}$$

Since $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{C}^n$, they can be written as linear combinations of $\mathbf{f_i}$:

$$ \mathbf{u} = \mathcal{F}\mathbf{\hat{u}}$$
$$ \mathbf{v} = \mathcal{F}\mathbf{\hat{v}}$$

where $\mathbf{\hat{u}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{v}}$ are the linear combination coefficients put into a vector.

Since the columns of $\mathcal{F}$ form the complete set of eigenvectors of $\mathcal{A}$, we have that:

$$\mathcal{A}\mathbf{f}_i = \lambda_i\mathbf{f}_i$$

where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue associated with eigenvector $\mathbf{f}_i$.

Thus, since $\mathcal{A}\mathcal{F} = [\mathcal{A}\mathbf{f}_1, ..., \mathcal{A}\mathbf{f}_i, ..., \mathcal{A}\mathbf{f}_n] = [\lambda_1\mathbf{f}_1, ..., \lambda_i\mathbf{f}_i, ..., \lambda_n\mathbf{f}_n]$, if we let $\mathcal{L}$ be the matrix with the $\lambda_i$ on its diagonals and $0$ elsewhere, we have that $\mathcal{L}\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{A}\mathcal{F}$.

Then $\mathcal{A}\mathbf{u} = \mathcal{A}\mathcal{F}\mathbf{\hat{u}} = \mathcal{L}\mathcal{F}\mathbf{\hat{u}} = \mathcal{F}\mathbf{\hat{v}}$.

That's where I am at right now. I want to work towards showing that $\mathcal{L}\mathbf{\hat{u}} = \mathbf{\hat{v}}$, but the way $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are arranged right now make it difficult for me to show that...

Could you give me a hint to help me out?

Comment: What exactly is your goal here?

Comment: The equation in the sentence "Thus, since..." is wrong, check again.

Comment: @vadim123 I want to work towards showing that $\mathcal{L}\mathbf{\hat{u}} = \mathbf{\hat{v}}$

Comment: @TroyWoo Thanks for pointing that out; I think I have fixed it now?

Comment: @user89 This is not the only mistake. $\mathcal F\mathcal L=\mathcal A\mathcal F$. It seems you don't have a good sense of left/right multiplication of matrices. Go through Gilbert Strang's linear algebra video lectures (in 1.5x or 2x preferably) to pick up the education you missed or never received.

Comment: @TroyWoo You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Troy Woo pointed out in the comments, there is a mistake in the paragraph starting with "Thus, since...". Here is the corrected version, which subsequently also helps me easily show what I needed to:

Thus, since $\mathcal{A}\mathcal{F} = [\mathcal{A}\mathbf{f}_1, ..., \mathcal{A}\mathbf{f}_i, ..., \mathcal{A}\mathbf{f}_n] = [\lambda_1\mathbf{f}_1, ..., \lambda_i\mathbf{f}_i, ..., \lambda_n\mathbf{f}_n]$, if we let $\mathcal{L}$ be the matrix with the $\lambda_i$ on its diagonals and $0$ elsewhere, we have that $\mathcal{F}\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{A}\mathcal{F}$.

Then $\mathcal{A}\mathbf{u} = \mathcal{A}\mathcal{F}\mathbf{\hat{u}} = \mathcal{F}\mathcal{L}\mathbf{\hat{u}} = \mathcal{F}\mathbf{\hat{v}} \implies \mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}\mathcal{L}\mathbf{\hat{u}} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}\mathbf{\hat{v}} \implies \mathcal{L}\mathbf{\hat{u}} = \mathbf{\hat{v}}$; which is what we wanted to show.